# How to add XNA Content Pipeline to Silverlight 5 in Visual Studio Web 2010 Express?

Tags: c#, silverlight-toolkit, xna-4.0, silverlight-5.0, visual-studio-express

[The Silverlight 5 XNA samples](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2011/09/01/silverlight-5-rc-what-s-new-in-the-3d-world.aspx), I presume are built in Visual Studio Professional editions as when when opening them in Visual Web Express 2010 it cannot open the Content Projects.

NB: I have [reported the issue here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/745085/cannot-create-and-edit-silverlight-5-xna-content-pipeline-projects-using-visual-studio-web-developer-2010-express), so watch out for a resolution there.

How can I use the Content Pipeline for a Silverlight 5 application using Visual Studio 2010 express editions? Or if that is not possible - how can I at least use the ContentManager to import pre-built .xnb files?

(I have all the requirements, apart from Pro edition it seems, and can draw primitives. I can actually run the platformer sample so there must be way)

[image]

Comment: I think you're mixing versions. Visual Web Dev Express is not Visual Studio 2010 Express. You have to install XNA Game Studio to do XNA dev, including from Silverlight: http://www.silverlight.net/downloads

Comment: trust me i have done that - 100 times over - I have installed XNA Game Studio, im not the only one: http://silverlight.codeplex.com/workitem/9613

Comment: Ok, that wasn't obvious from your original question. Have you tried the solution offered in the work item you've linked?

Comment: The one about installing XNA 4.0 instead of XNA 4.0 Refresh? Yes.

Comment: Have you tried creating the project with Visual C# Express or the "for Windows Phone" edition?

Comment: You cannot create a Silverlight Project from Visual C# Express - I can and have created XNA games (Windows Game 4.0) from Visual C# Express. I can not create any Windows Phone projects - I have installed nothing to do with Windows Phone

Comment: For the Windows Phone stuff: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27570 'Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone' => this allows both XNA and Silverlight (it's in fact a bundled Visual C# 2010 Express). Maybe it would work?

Comment: yes but thats for phone projects - im not intersted in phone projects

Comment: It's not only for WinPho: it allows XNA creation for Windows and Xbox360 too, that's why I'm suggesting it.

Comment: i dont follow - i already have xna and visual studio c# express - I make games for windows and xbox with it.

Comment: Ok, well I've got no more suggestions then, if you need a working project made from a paid version, I could provide one.

Comment: Thanks, im sure it does with professional - the samples are no doubt working copies - so no need.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft XNA Game Studio 4.0 is not supported in the Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 Express product SKU. See the MSDN article from here, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203916.aspx, portions of which are copied here for your convenience.

> **Microsoft Visual Studio 2010**
>
> XNA Game Studio 4.0 Refresh leverages the Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
>   development environment, extending it for game development. XNA Game
>   Studio 4.0 Refresh works with any of the following Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 2010 products.
>
> - Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone
> - Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express Edition
> - Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional Edition

To create or modify an XNA Content Project, Open the project in a supported edition of the Express SKU's.